# Pipedrive API using Python3 limits deal output to 1000 deals

Tags: python, api

I have written a Python3 script to retrieve all ldeal information from Pipedrive and deposit into an Excel csv file. 
I am unable to work out why I can only retrieve the first 1,000 deals, when there are over 2,500 in the database.  Any advise would be appreciated.

The script is:
import requests
import json
import csv

```
API_TOKEN = "<SECRET API KEY>"
FILTER = False # Apply Filtering.
FILTER_READABLE = True # Filter uses human-readable field names, not just ids/hashes.
FILTER_FIELDS = [ # Fields to Include, separated by commas, example below. Make sure spelling is exact. Run without filter enabled to see exact names.

]

EXAMPLE_FILTER = [
    "ID",
    "Expected close date",
    "Email messages count",
]


DEALS_BASE_URL = "https://api.pipedrive.com/v1/deals/"
DEALFIELDS_BASE_URL = "https://api.pipedrive.com/v1/dealFields/"

DEALFIELDS = {}
DEALFIELDS_OPTIONS = {}

end_last = 0
while True:
    req = requests.get(DEALFIELDS_BASE_URL, params={"api_token": API_TOKEN, "start": end_last, "limit": 5000})
    response = json.loads(req.text)
    if not response.get("data", None):
        print("Invalid Request. Check API Token!")
        quit(1)

    for field in response.get("data", []):
        DEALFIELDS[field["key"]] = field["name"]
        if field["field_type"] == "enum":
            DEALFIELDS_OPTIONS[field["key"]] = ("enum", {str(item["id"]): item["label"] for item in field["options"]})
        elif field["field_type"] == "set":
            DEALFIELDS_OPTIONS[field["key"]] = ("set", {str(item["id"]): item["label"] for item in field["options"]})

    if not response.get("additional_info", {}).get("pagination", {}).get("more_items_in_collection", False):
        break

    end_last = end_last + 5000


DEALS = []

end_last = 0
while True:
    req = requests.get(DEALS_BASE_URL, params={"api_token": API_TOKEN, "start": end_last, "limit": 5000})
    response = json.loads(req.text)
    if not response.get("data", None):
        quit()

    for deal in response.get("data", []):
        new_deal = {}
        for key, item in deal.items():
            if type(item) is dict:
                item = item["name"]

            if key in DEALFIELDS:
                if FILTER and FILTER_READABLE and DEALFIELDS[key] not in FILTER_FIELDS:
                    continue
                if FILTER and not FILTER_READABLE and key not in FILTER_FIELDS:
                    continue
                if key in DEALFIELDS_OPTIONS:
                    if DEALFIELDS_OPTIONS[key][0] == "enum":
                        if item is None:
                            continue
                        new_deal[DEALFIELDS[key]] = DEALFIELDS_OPTIONS[key][1][str(item)]
                    elif DEALFIELDS_OPTIONS[key][0] == "set":
                        if item is None:
                            continue
                        new_deal[DEALFIELDS[key]] = str(",".join([DEALFIELDS_OPTIONS[key][1][i] for i in item.split(",")]))
                    continue
                new_deal[DEALFIELDS[key]] = item
            else:
                if FILTER and key not in FILTER_FIELDS:
                    continue
                new_deal[key] = item
        DEALS.append(new_deal)

    if not response.get("additional_info", {}).get("pagination", {}).get("more_items_in_collection", False):
        break

    end_last = end_last + 5000

fieldnames = []
for deal in DEALS:
    for key, item in deal.items():
        if key not in fieldnames:
            fieldnames.append(key)

output_csv = open("out.csv", "w", encoding="utf-8")
out = csv.DictWriter(output_csv, fieldnames=fieldnames)
out.writeheader()
for deal in DEALS:
    out.writerow({str(key).strip(): str(item).strip() for key, item in deal.items()})
output_csv.close()
```

Answer (score -1):

Dont know if you ever got an answer to this elsewhere but think pipedrive api limits is 500 not 5000 so change that

Comment: Don't know why this would be down voted.  The limit is definetly 500. So when you add 5000 on the first iteration your start is now 5000, which will return nothing if you only have 2500.